# Beginner programming exercises (Java): recursively counting instances of substring in string (.equals()?)

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am working through a set of online exercises found at Codingbat.com for my own amusement. One set of exercises focuses on recursive programming. In one of those exercises I wrote the following function to return the frequency of char 'x' within a passed string:

```
       public int countX(String str) {
/*Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of lowercase 'x' 
chars in the string.*/
            if (str.length()< 1){
                return 0;
            }else if (str.charAt(0) == 'x'){
                return countX(str.substring(1)) + 1;
            }else{
                return countX(str.substring(1));
            }
}
```

According to the Codingbat site, this worked fine.

The next exercise was to count the frequency of the *substring* "hi" within a string. I tried to adapt my previous method, using `substring()` instead of `charAt()`:

```
       public int countHi(String str) {
/*Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of times lowercase 
"hi" appears in the string.*/
              if (str.length()< 2){
                return 0;
            }else if (str.substring(0, 1).equals("hi")){
                return countHi(str.substring(1)) + 1;
            }else{
                return countHi(str.substring(1));
            }
}
```

However, this always returns 0. It looks like the testing condition

```
 }else if (str.substring(0, 1).equals("hi")){
```

is never met, but I can't work out why. Hope someone can help!

**EDIT :**

As Steve and JustinKSU pointed out, I was returning a single character substring. I thought that the index numbers in the `substring()` method referred to the index of characters as if they were stored in an array (where 0 would be first character, 1 second etc.) It looks like a better way to think about it is that the `substring()` indexes represent the count of character separators in the string, starting with a separator preceding the first character, (such that `substring(0, 1)` *encapsulates* the first character).

Comment: The second parameter to `substring()` is *exclusive*. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.substring(0, 1)`
will only return one character so it will never match "hi" which has 2 characters. You should try

`str.substring(0, 2)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
str.substring(0, 2)
```

Comment: agreed: see answer to Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using subString() and get rid of the complexity.

```
public static int countHi(String str){
      if(str.length() > 0){
         if(str.contains("hi")){
           return  countHi(str.replaceFirst("hi","")) + 1;
         }  
      }
     return 0;
}
```